# How can I get the EASession from NSStream?

Tags: ios, objective-c, bluetooth, external-accessory

We'd like to open 3 sockets via Bluetooth to one external accessory. To do this, I assume I should create 3 separate EASessions with the same openSessionForProtocol: method using the same protocol.

Now the issue I have is that in stream:handleEvent: I'd like to know which EASession the current NSStream belongs to, but it doesn't look like there's a way to do this. Has anyone done this before or knows how this can be accomplished?

Answer (score 1):

In this case, I would create a dictionary mapping from the `NSStream` back to the `EASession` and make it available to your delegate of the `NSStream`s.   It's a simple solution, but slightly faster than looping through all of the `EASession`s looking at each stream for a match.

Another solution is to have separate delegate objects for each stream, but based on your question, that doesn't seem to be the solution you are perusing.